# Tablix dynamically moves up when theres no data

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I have 3 separate tablix, and each one of them are driven by group:

- Tablix1: ORX
- Tablix2: CSS
- Tabli3: WST

and they are stacked on top of each other. Currently, if one of the tablix has no data it leaves a whitespace on the report.

How can I make a specific tablix dynamically move up if the other tablix has no data? For example, Tablix 1 and Tablix 2 has no data, I want tablix 3 to move up replacing Tablix 1.  Is this possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This can be caused by a lot of things, but the obvious thing to discount is to check is that you're hiding the tablix (setting Hidden = True) if there are no rows returned?

[image]